# Azure migration from ASM to ARM

Tags: azure, migration

how to migrate a single vm from ASM to ARM?

I'm trying to migrate a single vm from ASM to an existing ARM. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-overview#migration-of-virtual-machines-in-a-virtual-network this micsoft doc eplains how to migrate everything from ASM to ARM but I need just one singe vm to be migrated to an existing ARM. Please guide me if someone knows. I'm very new to the cloud environment. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All of the steps are listed [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps#step-1-plan-for-migration).  In Step 6, is where the action happens.  You need to first determine if your Classic VM is a Cloud Service (not in a VNET) or if it's in a VNET.  If its a Cloud Service you must move it to a ARM VNET (Option 1 creates a new VNET for you, Option 2 lets you migrate to an existing VNET.

If your Classic VM is already in a VNET (`Get-AzureService | ft Servicename` will return an error). To migrate virtual machines in a virtual network, you migrate the virtual network. The virtual machines automatically [migrate with the virtual network](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/migration-classic-resource-manager-ps#step-61-option-2---migrate-virtual-machines-in-a-virtual-network).

**Please run all the validation commands before attempting a migration.**

---

**Bonus way** is to take a classic VM and use the VHD to create a new VM that uses the Resource Manager deployment model and managed disks. For the best results, **Stop** the classic VM in the Azure portal before creating the snapshot.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/create-vm-specialized-portal